# Align multiline equation with expression after equal sign for another equation

Tags: math-mode

I want to write the following equation

```
\begin{equation}
\label{gaussian-equation3}
    G_{\sigma}(x, y) & =  g_{\sigma}(x)\cdot g_{\sigma}(y) \\
    & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(\frac{-y^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
    
\end{equation}
```

How can I align the second equation which only contains after equal to and that should come just beneath the previous equal to

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the `aligned` environment provided by `amsmath` (or just use `mathtools` which loads `amsmath` automatically).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{gaussian-equation3}
  \begin{aligned}
    G_{\sigma}(x, y) & = g_{\sigma}(x)\cdot g_{\sigma}(y) \\
    & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(\frac{-y^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

**EDIT**: Additional information: if you want several equations aligned and each of them has its own equation number tag, you may directly use the `align` environment instead of the nested `equation` and `aligned`, like

```
some text in the document
\begin{align}
  A&=B+C\\
  E&=mc^2
\end{align}
```